# Combining declaration and initialization with overloaded `=`

Tags: c++, initialization, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I'm new to C++ (but not new to programming--I know Java pretty thoroughly), so this may have a simple answer I'm just overlooking.

> **Question in a nutshell:** What (if anything) is the difference between writing:
>
> ```
> classType a = b;
> ```
>
> and writing
>
> ```
> classType a;
> a = b;
> ```
>
> specifically when `b` is a reference variable in a function and when `=` is overloaded?

**Details/background:**

I'm working on a custom `vect` class, which will (eventually) hold n-tuples that behave like vectors in `R^n` (that is, math-style vectors, not STL-style vectors).  As such, I've overloaded the `=` operator to copy the components from `rhs` to `lhs`.

However, I've found that, **when my rhs is a reference variable in a function,** the combined declaration/initialization makes the rhs and lhs reference the *same object*, while the separate initialization keeps them as *different objects*.

In my program below, this is evidenced as `v2 = v1 * 10` results in both `v2` and `v1` being set equal to `v1*10` when I use the single-line `vect a = b`, but behaves as expected when I write `vect a; a=b` in the definition of `*`.

**Minimal Compilable Example:**

I apologize for its length, but this is pared down as much as I could get it at first try.  I'll keep looking for ways to reduce.

The problem occurs in the overloading of the `*` operator.  I've commented there as to what change is required to exhibit the problem.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h> //For toString method 
#include<sstream>  //For toString method

//===================================================
// Namespace for organization
namespace linalg {
    class vect {
        private:
            //int length;
            double* baseArray;
        public:
            //Constructor
            vect() { baseArray = new double[3]; }

            //TODO: Change so edits to arrayArg do not show up in the baseArray.
            vect(double arrayArg[3]) { baseArray = arrayArg; }

            //Returns a string for printing
            std::string toString();

            //Returns the element at given index
            double getElementAt(int) const;

            //Operator overloading:
            vect& operator=(const vect &rhs);
            friend vect operator*(double num, const vect &v);
    };

    //===================================================
    // General Methods
    // elementAt : return s the given element.  
    double vect::getElementAt(int i) const {
        return baseArray[i];
    }

    // toString : behaves like Java convention:
    //toString : gives string representation
    std::string vect::toString() {
        std::string retVal;

        retVal.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            //Convert the number to a string
            std::ostringstream num;
            num << baseArray[i];

            //Append the number to the return value
            retVal.append(num.str());

            //Comma separated
            if (i < 3-1) retVal.append(", ");
        }
        retVal.append("]");

        return retVal;
    }

    //===================================================
    // Operator overloads
    //Overload '=' : copies the other vector into this vector
    vect& vect::operator= (const vect &rhs) {
        //Check for self-assignment:
        if (this == &rhs) {
            return *this;
        }

        //Copy the rhs into this vector
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            baseArray[i] = rhs.getElementAt(i);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    //Overload scalar multiplication
    vect linalg::operator*(double num, const vect &v) {
        //CHANGE THIS to a single-line assignment/initialization, and the problem occurs.
        vect result;
        result = v;

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            result.baseArray[i] *= num;
        }

        return result;
    }
};

using namespace linalg;
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double a[3] = {2, 4, 8};
    double b[3] = {5, 1, 9};

    vect v1(a);
    vect v2(b);

    v1 = 10*v2;

    cout << v1.toString() << endl;
    cout << v2.toString() << endl; 

    system("pause"); //Pause the windows terminal

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Question: why are you allocation `baseArray` dynamically? if it's always 3 you don't need to (you should use `std::array<double, 3>`. If it's size varies, you should either store the pointer in `std::unique_ptr<double>` or use `std::vector<double>`

Comment: @Borgleader I want to make it a variable length array eventually, but thought it would be best to work with a fixed-length case first (for simplicities' sake).  I was guessing that C++'s handling of dynamically sized arrays would be similar to Java, but evidently that is not the case.  (tl;dr: I was trying to make it easily extendable to arrays of length `n`, but it appears I have not done so.) `:)`

Comment: Well you have, but you're doing extra work (i.e: managing memory yourself). By using vector you would have the same functionality without having to deal with memory management. (You could also use templates).

Comment: @Borgleader I think I may end up using `vector`...  I did consider templates, but I plan on using this class such that I don't always know the length of my array at compile time.  (My understanding is that template arguments need to be known at compile-time.)

Comment: `vect result = v` calls the *copy-constructor*, not the *copy-assignment* operator which you have overloaded. You need to implement the copy-constructor as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that `vect a = b;` performs *copy initialization* whereas `vect a; a = b;` performs *copy assignment.* Copy initialization calls the copy constructor, whereas copy assignment calls the overloaded `operator=`.

In your code, your copy assignment operator copies one vector's elements over into another, which is good. However, your copy constructor simply sets `baseArray` of the LHS to point to the same block of memory as that of the RHS, without copying any vector elements. When two pointers point to the same memory, of course modifying one also modifies the other.